# stripping inline tags with python's lxml

Tags: python, xml, tags, lxml

I have to deal with two types of inline tags in xml documents. The first type of tags enclose text that I want to keep in-between. I can deal with this with lxml's

```
etree.tostring(element, method="text", encoding='utf-8')
```

The second type of tags include text that I don't want to keep. How can I get rid of these tags and their text? I would prefer not to use regular expressions, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that [`strip_tags`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) and [`strip_elements`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_elements) are what you want in each case.  For example, this script:

```
from lxml import etree

text = "<x>hello, <z>keep me</z> and <y>ignore me</y>, and here's some <y>more</y> text</x>"

tree = etree.fromstring(text)

print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)

# Remove the <z> tags, but keep their contents:
etree.strip_tags(tree, 'z')

print '-' * 72
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)

# Remove all the <y> tags including their contents:
etree.strip_elements(tree, 'y', with_tail=False)

print '-' * 72
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

... produces the following output:

```
<x>hello, <z>keep me</z> and <y>ignore me</y>, and
here's some <y>more</y> text</x>

------------------------------------------------------------------------
<x>hello, keep me and <y>ignore me</y>, and
here's some <y>more</y> text</x>

------------------------------------------------------------------------
<x>hello, keep me and , and
here's some  text</x>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Mark Longair: Is there a way to use `strip_tags()` to strip all the child tags (and merge the text in the childs to the parent)?