# Python 3.3: Process inlineXML

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, stanford-nlp, inline-xml

Whilst trying to tag named entities with the stanford NRE tool, I get this kind of output:

```
A jury in <ORGANIZATION>Marion County Superior Court</ORGANIZATION> was expected to begin deliberations in the case on <DATE>Wednesday</DATE> or <DATE>Thursday</DATE>.
```

Of course processing any XML without a root does not work, so I added this:

```
<root>A jury in <ORGANIZATION>Marion County Superior Court</ORGANIZATION> was expected to begin deliberations in the case on <DATE>Wednesday</DATE> or <DATE>Thursday</DATE>.</root>
```

I tried building a tree with this method: [stripping inline tags with python's lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476548/stripping-inline-tags-with-pythons-lxml) but it does not work... It yields this error on the line `tree = etree.fromstring(text)`:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 1, column 1793
```

Does anyone know a solution for this? Or perhaps another method which allows me to build a tree from any text with inlineXML tags, keeping only the tagged tokens and removing/ignoring the rest of the text.

Comment: What's at column 1793 of the actual "XML" you're trying to parse? A `&`?

Comment: According to python (text[1793]), it's the letter 'e'. There are multiple ampersands in the text, the first one occuring at 1953.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did it without using a parser or a tree but just used regular expressions. This is the code that works nice and fast:

```
import re
NER = ['TIME','LOCATION','ORGANISATION','PERSON','MONEY','PERCENT','DATA']
entities = {}
for cat in NER:
    regex_cat = re.compile('<'+cat+'>(.*?)</'+cat+'>')
    entities[cat] = re.findall(regex_cat,data)
```

Here `data` is just a string of text. It uses regular expressions to find all entities of a category specified in `NER` and stores it as is list in a dictionary. This could be used for all inlineXML strings where `NER` is just a list of all possible tags in the string.